SXA Asset optimizer taking scripts twice when set to "Concatenate and minify"
I'm using Sitecore 10.3 and SXA 10.3
When I turn on the script optimizer from /sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Theming/Optimiser/Scripts, and set it to "Concatenate and minify", and publish, it creates an `Optimized-min.js1 file, however I found that inside that file all of the js is included twice.
The file looks like its contents are duplicated then concatenated, this is causing some issues for us on production.
I have found that setting the optimizer to "Concatenate" only doesn't create the issue, and we don't have any errors when disabling the optimizer all together either.
I have checked the Site settings at /sitecore/content/Sitename/Sitename/Presentation/Page Designs, they are both set to "Default" which means it's inheriting the global settings.
The environment is 1 CM and 2 CDs, and I made sure that only one optimized-min.js file is created in the web db on publish, it's just that it looks like its going over the scripts two times to create the file. It's worth noting that this is also happening on our standalone test environment.
Has anyone faced a similar issue? Or has an explanation for why this is happening? I've been searching for a while but couldn't find a similar scenario happening for others.
